# Using Javascript, increase scale of a section from .75 to 1 using window scroll value

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I have a very simple function, that waits until a section is "within view" of the viewport. I'm wanting to animate/"grow" the section from something like .75 of it's natural size, to 1.

When I do this, the calculation often stops at say, 0.975 or something, leaving a very small (but very annoying) gap.

Also—it looks a little jittery, and I've tried to use requestAnimationFrame to negate any performance issues, but it still doesn't look great.

```
const CaseStudyGrow = () => {
    let ticking         = false;
    let case_studies    = document.querySelectorAll('.case_studies');

    if (Object.values(case_studies).length <= 0) {
        return;
    }

    const animate = () => {
        let scroll  = Math.round(window.scrollY);
        let vh      = Math.round(window.innerHeight);

        Object.values(case_studies).forEach(casestudy => {
            let offset = Math.round(casestudy.offsetTop);

            // calc 3/4s of the viewport, to animate the scroll when the section is within a quarter of the viewport from being in view.
            let q       = vh / 4;
            let grace   = q * 3;  
            let target  = parseInt(offset) - parseInt(grace);

            if (((scroll + vh) - offset) > target) {
                let grow    = ((scroll + (vh + vh / 2)) - offset) / 1000;
                grow        = grow.toFixed(5);

                if ((grow >= 0.75) && (grow <= 1)) {
                    casestudy.style.setProperty('--grow', grow);
                }
            } 

            // else {
            //  casestudy.style.setProperty('--grow', '0.75');
            // }
        });
    };

    document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }, false);
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', CaseStudyGrow, false);
```

Lastly, if you scroll *really quickly* up and down, the calculation is nowhere near, often stopping around 0.8 or something.

I'm definitely not doing this correctly but I need a solution.

Any help hugely appreciated.

Matt

Tried using Math.ceil / Math.round to get full values.

Tried using requestAnimationFrame to smooth performance.

Comment: This question lacks a functional example of the defect, which is probably why you haven't gotten an answer yet. I suggest that you convert your scroll event listener that calls requestAnimationFrame to a requestAnimationFrame loop that checks the scroll position. Check at the beginning of your animation method to see if the scroll position has changed from the last time and return if it hasn't, if it has changed do your "drawing" logic.